# Can I connect two Raspberry Pis to one 5" Display via an HDMI switch?

Tags: hdmi, display, output

I have two Raspberry Pis running very different systems. I want to build an enclosure so that I can use a single 5" display ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076M399XX)) for both Pis.

The setup I'm envisioning would rely on an HDMI splitter with a switch ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079JQ9XXV)) so that I can press a button and switch inputs:

```
Pi 3 (1)----HDMI----|  SIGNAL  |
                   
                    | SPLITTER |----HDMI-----| 5" DISPLAY |

Pi 3 (2)----HDMI----| W/SWITCH |
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, perfectly possible. Obviously just make sure you have easy access to the button in your enclosure. You can do that with more or less any sort of hdmi device. For example I have a ps4 connected to my TV along with a Nintendo switch. All I have to do is turn the TV on and press the button on the switch to flick between the two.